# Giving local xml file as an input to a java class in android

Tags: java, android, xml, file

I have a local xml file called coffee.xml inside assets folder.

I have the following structure:

```
1 activity called Game.java
1 class called Units.java
1 class called MyUnit.java which extends Units.java
```

Now, I'm trying to give the coffee.xml file as an input in the MyUnits.java file.

I saw many solutions like using

```
getResources() OR
classLoader() etc...
```

Nothing works. I also tried giving direct path "C:\Users\MyName\Workspace ..... coffee.xml"
That too doesn't work. I am totally confused on how to give this file as an input.

Please advise. Thanks!
(stack overflow is getting annoying with these auto-code-detect features... which is failing miserably.)
======================More info========================

In the constructor of the MyUnit.java, I am calling a function called retrieve()

This retrive() function basically takes input of the coffee.xml file and retrieves all the info from the nodes and assigns it to the MyUnit.java class object. I am using SAXParser for doing so.

Its all basic like

```
try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            ....

         }
         };

         saxParser.parse(<your XML File>, handler); <------Problem here
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I need to know, how do I give my local file coffee.xml as an input on the marked line.

Comment: you have to elaborate this is very vague, you can refer to the xml with 'R' R.layout.coffee, im not sure exactly what your trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are loaded via the AssetManager, which is returned via a Context's

```
getAssets()
```

method. Therefore, in your Game Activity, you can call

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
XmlResourceParser xmlParser = assetManager.openXmlResourceParser("coffee.xml");
MyUnit unit = new MyUnit(xmlParser);
```

From there, you'd want to read up on [XmlResourceParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html) to extract attributes/tags from your XML file. A good example on how to iterate through the XML file can be found on the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) page (which XmlResourceParser implements).

In the case of using a SAXParser (rather than the Android provided parser), you can instead use:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("coffee.xml");
MyUnit unit = new MyUnit(is);
```

And then in place of your file name, use

```
saxParser.parse(is, handler);
```

Comment: getAssets() isn't working. It works for activity. However, the MyUnits.java class is extending another simply Units.java class and not an activity. That is the whole problem. :(

Comment: Yes, you need to call getAssets from an Android context, such as an Activity and pass that on to your Units.java class. There is no other way to retrieve the XML file as the assets are embedded within your application's APK, rather than a separate file on the Android device.

Comment: I am using a SAXParser in the MyUnits.java. Now, I managed to use the method u suggested, created a XmlResourceParser object as you suggested, can I give that object as an input to the saxParser.parse(<xmlFile>, handler) as mentioned in the code?

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding a section on using SAXParser. In that case, instead of using assetManager.openXmlResourceParser, you can use assetManager.open to get an InputStream which you can then use in place of your <xmlFile> when building the SAXParser.